# Generate the output of the file in the next line

Tags: shell-script, shell, files

I have 3 files ex- **abc.txt, def.txt & xyz.txt**. I've generate one shell script where I want to content of these 3 files should appear line wise like as below-

```
abc ---- 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
def ---- 3  5  7  9 11 13 15
xyz ---- 4  8 12 16 20 24 28
```

Also the content of the files should be like this manner & every value in parallel wise. Could you please help me to generate the shell script.
But in actual when i run script then it is showing like-

```
abc ---- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
def ---- 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
xyz ---- 4 8 12 16 20 24 28
```

So I want to arrange like above content of the output. Where I used in the script for the above requirement-

```
 for f in abc.txt def.txt xyz.txt; do (cat "${f}"; echo) >> output.txt; done
|awk '{printf "%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7} output.txt > final_output.txt
```

Is it good approach to generate the script

Comment: Please give details on how the content of your files looks like. Are all numbers in different lines in these files, or are they all on the same line, or mixed?

Comment: @AdminBee I've updated please see. Actually I want the output in above format.

Comment: @MdWasi The question is what the _input_ (e.g. abc.txt) looks like, though.

Comment: @DonHolgo After run the shell script, arrangement of the data like that I am getting which mentioned above in the question is not as expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the columns command

```
./your_script |  column -t -s' '
```

This will be close to your desired output but the numbers would not be right-justified

```
abc  ----  1  2  3   4   5   6   7
def  ----  3  5  7   9   11  13  15
xyz  ----  4  8  12  16  20  24  28
```

To right justify the numbers just pipe the output of your shell script to rev and columns command like this

```
./your_script | rev | column -t -s' '  | rev
```

- The first `rev` will reverse every line
- Then the columns command will create columns with space as the delimiter
- Finally , the last `rev` will revert back the original line - giving you right aligned numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. But arrangement that I want to get as you mentioned above it is not showing like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use @amisax' answer to rewrite your script to remove redundancies. The following should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in abc.txt def.txt xyz.txt
do
    echo "$f --- " "$(cat $f)" >> ct_output.txt
done

column -t -s' ' ct_output.txt
```

This creates a temporary file in which the every line contains the name of the input file, followed by its content (assuming *the content is one one line only*), and pipes this file through `column` as explained by @amisax. This should yield the desired

```
user@host $ ./columnize.sh
abc.txt  ---  1  2  3   4   5   6   7
def.txt  ---  3  5  7   9   11  13  15
xyz.txt  ---  4  8  12  16  20  24  28
```